# How do I refresh my RadTreeView

Tags: c#, telerik, radtreeview

I have a RadTreeView that isn't getting updated when the datasource changes.

This is the code in my ascx.

```html
<div class="demo-container size-thin" style="display: inline-block">
    <telerik:RadTreeView RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="AssessmentCriteriaTree" runat="server"  Width="200px" Height="620px"
        OnClientNodeClicked="OnClientNodeClicked" OnNodeDataBound="AssessmentCriteriaTree_NodeDataBound">
        <DataBindings>
            <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding Expanded="True"></telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding>
        </DataBindings>
    </telerik:RadTreeView>
</div>
```

In the code behind the data binding happens with this code.

```
DataTable dtTree = ds.Tables[0];
AssessmentCriteriaTree.DataTextField = "Val";
AssessmentCriteriaTree.DataFieldID = "ID";
AssessmentCriteriaTree.DataFieldParentID = "ParentID";
AssessmentCriteriaTree.DataSource = dtTree;
AssessmentCriteriaTree.DataBind();
```

When the page loads initially, the tree is built correctly but when the same code is hit that changes the datasource, the tree doesn't change.  When debugging the OnNodeDataBound event I can see that the new data is being processed so it looks like that part is working correctly.  It just doesn't update in the UI.

Comment: How and when are you setting the datasource (Page_Init, control postback, etc)? Are you using the ajax manager or update panels at all?

Comment: This code runs in page_load. I am not using ajax manager or update panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another section on the page was where the button was to trigger the update to the datasource.  It was in a RadAjaxPanel.  My treeView was not inside the RadAjaxPanel.  I moved it inside and it is now getting refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a change in the underlying datasource you should call DataBind() on the treeview to refresh its data.

Comment: I am calling DataBind on the treeview but its not updating. See the code I posted.

Comment: How and where do you change the data?